# Geometry problem: Hexagon $ABLCDK$ inscribed in a circle, prove $|NL||KP||MQ|=|KM||PN||LQ|$

Tags: geometry

Hexagon $ABLCDK$ is inscribed in a circle. Line $LK$ cuts line segments $AD, BC, AC, BD$ in points $M, N, P, Q$ respectively, prove $|NL||KP||MQ|=|KM||PN||LQ|$.

So, I have the solution, but I don't understand it.

The solution as given:

Let $$s=\sin\frac{AB}2,t=\sin\frac{BL}2,u=\sin\frac{LC+AK}2,\\v=\sin\frac{CK}2,w=\sin\frac{DK}2,x=\sin\frac{LD+AK}2.$$

Then we have:

$$\frac{|NL|\cdot|KP|\cdot|MQ|}{|KM|\cdot|PN|\cdot|LQ|}=\\ =\frac{|NL|}{|NC|}\cdot\frac{|NC|}{|NP|}\cdot\frac{|KP|}{|KA|}\cdot\frac{|KA|}{|KM|}\cdot\frac{|QM|}{|QD|}\cdot\frac{|QD|}{|QL|}=\\ =\frac tv\cdot\frac us\cdot\frac vu\cdot\frac xw\cdot\frac sx\cdot\frac wt = 1$$

What I don't understand is why is $\frac{|NL|}{|NC|}=\frac tv$, or why is $\frac{|NC|}{|NP|}=\frac us$. (I don't understand the others too but maybe I will if you explain those 2 to me.)

So my main question: Can you explain one or both of those 2 to me?

Second question (if not answered already): Why do we have $\sin\frac{AB}2$? Why sine of a side? What do we get from this?

Edit: So, $\sin\frac{AB}2$ refers to sine of half of the arc AB (not side). So, only the main question remains.

Edit: Question is answered in comments.

Comment: I believe that $\sin\frac{AB}{2}$ isn't the sine of (half of) a *side*, $\overline{AB}$; it's the sine of (half of) an *arc*, $\stackrel{\frown}{AB}$. In general, for chord $\overline{PQ}$ of a circle with diameter $d$, $$|\overline{PQ}| = d\;\sin\frac{\stackrel{\frown}{PQ}}{2}$$ This principle (together with the Inscribed Angle Theorem) is typically used in demonstrating the Law of Sines.

Comment: @Blue So the best I could come up with is $\frac{\sin\frac{BL}2}{\sin\frac{CK}2}=\frac{|BL|}{|CK|}$. How do I get to $\frac{|NL|}{|NC|}$? Is it because $BL$ and $CK$ are opposite equal angles?

Comment: By the Law of Sines in $\triangle NCL$, $$\frac{|NL|}{|NC|} = \frac{\sin\angle C}{\sin\angle L} = \frac{\sin(\stackrel{\frown}{BL}/2)}{\sin(\stackrel{\frown}{CK}/2)} = \frac{t}{v}$$

Comment: @Blue Oh, I see. One more question: can you explain why $\frac{|NC|}{|NP|} = \frac{\sin\frac{LC+AK}2}{\sin\frac{AB}2}$ and not $\frac{|NC|}{|NP|} = \frac{\sin\frac{LC}2}{\sin\frac{AB}2}$? Why is it $\sin\frac{LC+AK}2$ instead of $\sin\frac{LC}2$?

Comment: $\angle NPC$ is not an *inscribed* angle, so it's not half of a particular arc ... The edges of that angle determine *two* arcs: $\stackrel{\frown}{CL}$ and $\stackrel{\frown}{AK}$. The only *fair* thing to do (which happens to be the *correct* thing to do) is *average* those arcs: the angle measure is half the sum of the arcs. (Note that the Inscribed Angle Theorem actually does this: it averages the subtended arc with a "zero" arc. Moreover: If lines through a circle meet at a point *outside* the circle, then the angle measure is half the *difference* of the subtended arcs.)

Comment: Okay, I understand now. Thank you very much!

Comment: This discussion would make more sense to people with a picture. I'll post one as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this figure ...

[image]

... we can apply the Law of Sines in the two shaded triangles, then invoke the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle#Theorem) and [a relative](https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/angle-of-intersecting-chords-theorem):

$$\begin{align}
\triangle CNL: &\quad\frac{|NL|}{|NC|}= \frac{\sin\angle BCL}{\sin\angle CLK} = \frac{\sin\frac12\stackrel{\frown}{BL}}{\sin\frac12\stackrel{\frown}{CK}} \\[6pt]
\triangle CNP: &\quad\frac{|NC|}{|NP|}= \frac{\sin\angle CPL}{\sin\angle ACB} = \frac{\sin\frac12(\stackrel{\frown}{CL}+\stackrel{\frown}{AK})}{\sin\frac12\stackrel{\frown}{AB}}
\end{align}$$

This gives the first two ratios in the six-ratio product shown in the question. The remaining ratios are handled similarly.

Comment: How did you make the picture?

Comment: @Pero: I use [GeoGebra](http://geogebra.org) for my images.